# PHP: Subtracting 1 hour from the Dailight Savings Time one hour after the changeover

Tags: php, datetime, dst

I came across a weird thing in PHP. Being in the timezone `Europe/Oslo` I was subtracting one hour from the timestamp `2020-03-29 03:00:00` (which is exactly when the Dailight Savings Time shift happens) and it resulted in the exact same timestamp `2020-03-29 03:00:00`! It should have resulted in `2020-03-29 01:00:00`. How come it doesn't?

All the way up to `2020-03-29 03:59:59` it returns the exact same timestamp when subtracting one hour (tried both `sub()` and `modify()`). The next second after that it correctly results in `2020-03-29 03:00:00`.

You can reproduce it like this:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
echo (new \DateTime('2020-03-29 03:00:00'))->sub(new \DateInterval('PT1H'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I have tested this in both PHP 7.1.33, 7.3.10, and 7.3.18.

PS. Adding 1 hour to `2020-03-29 01:00:00` does correctly give `2020-03-29 03:00:00` though.

Comment: [This info](https://superuser.com/questions/1403444/why-does-php-7-3-2-show-the-wrong-time-and-ignores-timezone) appears related to what you describe.

Comment: The problem is, that the Datetime object carries the timezone. At 2 a.m. on DST day, the clock switches to 3 instantly. By subtracting 1 hour from 3 a.m. you'll come out at 2.a.m - and if you then format this date time in the timezone Oslo, it gets magically moved again to 3a.m.... welcome to the Twilight Zone!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that this is bad/buggy behaviour, you can avoid it by strictly only ever storing or computing dates in UTC. Consider time zones to be strictly for display purposes only, and you'll avoid a *lot* of headaches.

eg:

```
// input
$utc     = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$user_tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Oslo');
$input   = new DateTime('2020-03-29 03:00:00', $user_tz);
$storage = (clone $input)->setTimezone($utc);
var_dump(
    $input->format('c'),
    $storage->format('c')
);

// compute
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H');
$storage->sub($interval);
var_dump(
    $storage->format('c')
);

// display
$display = (clone $storage)->setTimezone($user_tz);
var_dump(
    $display->format('c')
);
```

Output:

```
string(25) "2020-03-29T03:00:00+02:00"
string(25) "2020-03-29T01:00:00+00:00"
string(25) "2020-03-29T00:00:00+00:00"
string(25) "2020-03-29T01:00:00+01:00"
```

Comment: Good point. I usually store in UTC but here I'm dealing with lots of hourly logging data which we are doing statistical SQL queries on. Therefore it would be really hard to do these day/hour grouping queries if we don't keep the data in the local timezone. Can of course convert it to UTC before doing arithmetic in PHP though...